# Programmatic access to a Resource protected by IBM APP ID

Tags: openid-connect, websphere-liberty, ibm-appid

I am trying to access a rest API secured by APP ID service instance.
I have tried two approaches to access the rest resource but alway I get `<title>Redirect To OP</title>` redirect HTML as the response instead of an actual resource.

**1. approach 1**
Using cloud directory user & and grant_type=password for token endpoint

1.1 I have added a user and password in cloud directory.

1.2 HTTP POST to `<oauthServer>/token` endpoint  with clientID and Secret as Basic authentication and `grant_type=password`, `username=<cloud_direcotry_user>`, `password=<password>`

1.3  I get access_token and Identity Token

1.4 Invoked protected resource with authorization header that has an access token and identity token as header value `'authorization' Bearer <accesstoken> <identity token>`

1.5  response contains redirect HTML instead of actual resource JSON/XML.

**Approach 2**

2.1 Fetch access token using `<oauthserverUrl>/token`  endpoint  and `grant_type=client_credentials`
add **Basic authentication with Client ID and Secret** as username and password

2.2 I got access token with type Bearer

2.3  invoke protected resource with **authorization** header

```
authorization: Bearer <access_toke>
```

2.4 I get the same redirect response`<title>Redirect To OP</title>` instead of actual resource JSON/XML

**___ New Update____**

Here is the iberty's openid connect client configuration of the resource provider.

```
<openidConnectClient id="<identifier>"
                     clientId= "${APPID_CLIENT_ID}"
                     clientSecret= "${APPID_CLIENT_SECRET}"                         authorizationEndpointUrl="${APPID_AUTH_SERVER}/authorization"
                     tokenEndpointUrl="${APPID_AUTH_SERVER}/token"
                     jwkEndpointUrl="${APPID_AUTH_SERVER}/publickeys"
                     issuerIdentifier="${APPID_AUTH_SERVER_ISSUER}"
                     tokenEndpointAuthMethod="basic"
                     signatureAlgorithm="RS256"
                     authFilterid="myAuthFilter"
                     trustAliasName="ng.bluemix.net"
                     trustStoreRef="appidtruststore"
                     redirectToRPHostAndPort="https://${env.APPID_SAMPLE_HOST}:${env.APPID_SAMPLE_SSL_PORT}"
         userIdentityToCreateSubject="email"
         inboundPropagation="supported"
         validationEndpointUrl="${APPID_AUTH_SERVER}/introspect"
         validationMethod="introspect"
```

/>

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using WebSphere Liberty and configured an OIDC client.
It seems that you should configure your OIDC client in your server.xml to support protected REST endpoints as stated in the documentation:

> 12. Optional: You can configure an OpenID Connect Client to optionally accept a valid OAuth 2.0 bearer access token as an authentication token without redirecting the request to an OpenID Connect provider. If a request contains a valid OAuth 2.0 bearer access token, then the Liberty OpenID Connect Client will automatically validate the access token, and create an authenticated subject based on the token validation result. If the request does not contain an access token or the access token is invalid, then the Liberty OpenID Connect Client continues to redirect the user to an OpenID Connect provider. This function enables the Liberty server to serve both the browser client and non-browser client like a RESTful client. You can add **inboundPropagation=”supported”** to the configuration to enable this function.

See: [Configuring an OpenID Connect Client in Liberty](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_config_oidc_rp.html)

Comment: Yes. Nitzan Nissim  this was my understanding. Mine is a client application. the actual resource is a rest resource hosted on a liberty servier and they have configured openid connect client. So When I pass access_token ,  the OpenID Connect client feature in resource provider liberty server would have validated and  give me the resource. instead I get an HTML response that has redirect page of OP as mentioned above.

Comment: Thank You Nitzan Nissim for the pointer. I will check to see if the openid connect client is configured that way based on the pointers you gave about inboundPropagation.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your approach 1, the header of "authorization Bearer accesstoken identity token" is not supported, it is supposed to be "authorization Bearer accesstoken".
2. Is accessToken an opaque token or JWT? can you post a sample JWT or result from opaque introspection?